# AWS EC2 Javascript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, memory, amazon-ec2

I am currently deploying a Node.js server using AWS EC2 t2.micro, Docker.

From yesterday, I suddenly got a Javascript heap out of memory error while trying to run the server.

I've been looking for a number of solutions and figured out how to directly increase the memory allocated to Node.js.

So I tried to fix it using the node --max-old-space-size command.

But my main file start `import "module-alias/register"` and and got `"Unexpected String"` error.

How can I fix this error?

When I run the server locally, it runs fine without errors.

This is error message

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[18:0x5e5b1c0]    19897 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 488.5 (491.2) -> 487.7 (492.2) MB, 774.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.113, current mu = 0.022) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[18:0x5e5b1c0]    20693 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 488.8 (491.2) -> 488.1 (492.7) MB, 769.6 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.1 ms in 17 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 796 ms) (average mu = 0.074, current mu = 0.033) allocati
<--- JS stacktrace --->
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 0xa04200 node::Abort() [node]
2: 0x94e4e9 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
3: 0xb7978e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
4: 0xb79b07 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
5: 0xd34395  [node]
6: 0xd34f1f  [node]
7: 0xd42fab v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
8: 0xd46b6c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
9: 0xd1524b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
10: 0x105b23f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
11: 0x1401219  [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! share_up@1.0.0 start: `ts-node src/main/server.ts`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the share_up@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-08T13_31_00_975Z-debug.log

> share_up@1.0.0 start /app
> ts-node src/main/server.ts
```

Please help me

Comment: The t2.micro instance has only 1Gib of RAM, which is not much, especially if you run Docker on it. Does the heap out of memory error happens right away after starting your server or after a specific action on it ?

Comment: Yes, I use docker-compose to run the server, and when I enter the run command, an error occurs in the node js server execution part and execution stops.

Comment: `ts-node` can exhaust a lot of memory if your project is large or has very compilcated types. You should compile the TypeScript into JavaScript with `tsc` as a build step, and run the compiled code with `node` instead of `ts-node`.

Comment: ok, i'll try it. thank you

Comment: As you told me, I tried using tsc, but at the time of using tsc I get a Javascript heap out of memory error.